# sed ignore line starting with regex

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace properties on a properties file using sed in a shell script; the command listed below works perfectly fine

```
sed "s!${KEY}=.*!${KEY}=${NEWVAL}!" infile > outfile
```

Issue - this guy replaces the matched "KEY" in comments as well.

example file:

```
###########
#ws.clients=http://abc123.com
ws.clients=http://123.com
###########
```

script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
KEY="ws.clients"
NEWVAL="http://abcd.com"
sed "s!${KEY}=.*!${KEY}=${NEWVAL}!" infile > outfile
```

output:

```
###########
#ws.clients=http://abcd.com
ws.clients=http://abcd.com
###########
```

I tried few ways but wasnt successful in escaping the line starting with "#"... suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a condition to the replace expression:

```
sed "/^[^#]/ s!${KEY}=.*!${KEY}=${NEWVAL}!" infile > outfile
```

`/^[^#]/` reads as "everything *but* a pound sign at the start of the line".

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
sed "s!^${KEY}=.*!${KEY}=${NEWVAL}!" infile > outfile
```

Just added `^` so that only ones starting from the beginning of line match. Well above ans should work too but that will have same problem if your line begins with `space`.